# package.json override dependencies peer dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, node-modules, package.json, peer-dependencies

When running `npm i` in one of my projects I get the follow error:

```
npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
npm ERR! node_modules/react
npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.2" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! peer react@"^16.13.1" from react-qr-barcode-scanner@1.0.6
npm ERR! node_modules/react-qr-barcode-scanner
npm ERR!   react-qr-barcode-scanner@"*" from the root project
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force, or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
```

I have read about the [overrides](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides) property in `package.json` but this only seems to work for overriding "regular" dependencies.

I do also know that I can simply run `npm i --legacy-peer-deps` as the error suggests but I can't help but wonder:

**Is there a way to override a dependencies peer dependencies without requiring `--legacy-peer-deps`?**

Comment: What exactly are you hoping to override? Is the [react-qr-barcode-scanner](https://github.com/jamenamcinteer/react-qr-barcode-scanner) package a direct dependency of your project or is it transitive (a dependency of a dependency)? That package appears to be abandoned. There's a [bug report asking for React 17 support](https://github.com/jamenamcinteer/react-qr-barcode-scanner/issues/24) in which somebody has made [a fork](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner)

Comment: @LiuNate good luck getting anywhere with your bounty. This question needs clarification and OP hasn't touched it in over 5 years

Comment: I saw this was asked only 3 months ago. I am having the same concern that my `npm` v8  does not override peerDeps and `npm install` never succeeds for those conflicting peerDeps deep in my deps.

Comment: @Phil the question was asked only 3 months ago, its May 17, 2022. Not May 2017. Just to clarify, I have yet to find a proper answer to this as well. My current solution is using the --legacy-peer-deps flag, which is less than ideal.

Comment: @Phil Basically, the react-qr-barcode-scanner package in this case works perfectly in React 17. The only thing preventing us from using it is the fact that it's package.json only lists React 16 as a peer dependency. Which fails npm's new peer dependency check. I wondered if there was a way to tell npm that that dependency has listed incorrect peer dependencies without explicitly having to run npm i with the --legacy-peer-deps flag and disabling the checks alltogether.

Comment: @Luze _"the question was asked only 3 months ago"_... I'm an idiot , thanks for the correction. If you've got `react-qr-barcode-scanner` as a direct dependency, consider using the [forked project](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner) with updated `package.json`

Comment: @Luze see also [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73572077/283366)

Comment: or just contribute back to that open source, what a WIN-WIN 

Answer (score 0):

This is a known [issue](https://github.com/jamenamcinteer/react-qr-barcode-scanner/issues/24), seems like author dropped support for this package.

You can replace with forked one to solve this problem, created by @steima

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@steima/react-qr-barcode-scanner

Answer (score -1):

`npm update ; npm i --force`

secondly. your next option is clear package.json. and npm init. and try installing latest versions of all dependencies. and never upgrade until absolutely necessary.