# Override NPM package with another package entirely

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm, package.json

According to the official NPM docs, `overrides` in `package.json` allows for overriding a package with another package entirely:

> Overrides provide a way to replace a package in your dependency tree
> with another version, **or another package entirely**. These changes can
> be scoped as specific or as vague as desired.

https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/package-json#overrides

However, I can't figure out how to replace a package with anything other than a changed version of the same package.

I'm trying to replace `node-sass` with `sass` in a transitive dependency but no configuration that I've tried works.

```
"overrides": {
  "node-sass": "sass@^1.3.0"
}

"overrides": {
  "node-sass": {
    ".": "sass@^1.3.0"
  }
}
```

Either of the above configuration produces the following NPM error:

```
Invalid tag name "sass@^1.3.0": Tags may not have any characters that encodeURIComponent encodes.
```

If I try something more rudimentary:

```
"overrides": {
  "node-sass": "sass"
}
```

NPM errors with:

```
No matching version found for node-sass@sass.
```

I'm on NPM v8.3.1.

Is it actually possible to replace a package with another package entirely or am I misunderstanding what's written in the docs?

Comment: Not a solution but you should definitely subscribe to [this issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4909) to get the docs improved

Comment: Potential solution here ~ https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4909#issuecomment-1144837588

Comment: @Phil thanks for the link to essentially this exact issue. somehow i completely missed it in my search.

Answer (score 7):

Based on a [comment in the Github issue linked](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/4909#issuecomment-1144837588) in @Phil's comment, I was able to override a package with another package entirely by using the `npm:` prefix:

```
"overrides": {
  "dependency": {
    "node-sass": "npm:sass@1.54.7"
  }
}
```

It's not documented in relation to `overrides` from what I can tell, so I don't know to what extent this feature is supported, but it appears to work in at least rudimentary cases.